# Does a version of Chu-Chu Rocket exist on PC?

Tags: chuchu-rocket

Is there a version of the Dreamcast puzzler [Chu-Chu Rocket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ChuChu_Rocket!) that runs on PC (any operating system)?

Comment: There used to be a Flash version made by Sega themselves. Where did that go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to play it in your browser, this should suffice:

http://upsidedownturtle.com/chuchu/

If you want to play the original on your computer, you can get it from GameTap:

www.gametap.com/video-games/Chu-Chu-Rocket!-20000949-23.html#download_Chu-Chu-Rocket!_gametap_130003750

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ChuChu_Rocket!) page for ChuChu Rocket, the game was only *officially* released for Dreamcast, Game Boy Advance, iOS and Android.

However if you want to play the original Dreamcast version on a PC, you may want to consider emulation. An emulator like [Demul](http://demul.emulation64.com/) should be able to run the game.